# How to use Naudio dll in visual studio 2010 "C" program

Tags: dll, naudio

Is it possible to load Naudio dll in c program(visual studio 2010). If it is possible please provide some example program for using Naudio dll function in c.

Comment: I'm sure it is possible, but the major purpose of NAudio is to provide .NET wrappers for audio APIs so you can use them in .NET applications. So if you're already in C, you would be better off calling the APIs directly, or finding an unmanaged audio library.

Comment: Agreed...  http://www.un4seen.com/bass.html is supposed to be pretty awesome for native work...